# The application built in C# cannot connect to the SQLlite database when it is published

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am new to C#, I built an application with a SQLITE database, which works fine on my computer, but it does work when I publish it and try it on another computer. It's impossible to connect to the SQL database.

I have searched plenty, on many forums, in French and English, but without success
so gar.

Here is my C# code

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder SQLCSB = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
SQLCSB.DataSource = @"C:\Users\Moi\source\repos\projetcsharp2\bases_de_donnees\base_exemple.db"; 

string ConnectionString = SQLCSB.ToString();

SQLiteConnection SQLC = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
SQLC.Open();

SQLiteCommand SQLCmd = SQLC.CreateCommand();
SQLCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ref,titre FROM table_choses";

SQLiteDataReader SQLDReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (SQLDReader.Read())
{
    // some results
}                    

SQLC.Close();
```

How can I do it?

I know I should change the path, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If the database does not exist on "the other computer" at the location specified in your connection string (`C:\Users\Moi\source\repos\projetcsharp2\bases_de_donnees\base_exemple.db`) it will not work

Comment: To put you on the right path... WHY do you expect the "other" computer has "C:\User\Moi.... DATABASE FILE" ?   Does your program create a database in THAT  location (intead of a relative path) ? If it does not exists are you creating one?   
if  (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Moi\source\repos\projetcsharp2\bases_de_donnees\base_exemple.db")) throw new Exception("Database does not exists");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers 
in fact I know it is a problem with the file location
The question: how to use relative path?

The database will not be created by the program, it is a collecton of songs lyricks.

Thanks again